# Getting only the latest item from a DynamoDB table and putting it into another DynamoDB table via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to copy the latest updates from one DynamoDB table and put them into another using Lambda. I have set up up a trigger in DynamoDB to update a Lambda function when a new entry happens on the table using the 'Blueprint'. I need help in putting the latest items in the new table.

Here is my Lambda code:

```
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log(record.eventID);
        console.log(record.eventName);
        console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);
    });
    callback(null, `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`);
};
```

This is the first time I am doing this so any help would be appreciated.

The items are trying to put into the table#2 are:

`{ "Item": { "Temp": "47.2", "Light": "29", "GWID": "BB00000002", "DateTm": "0\n18-05-05T16:44:39Z", "Status": "b", "ID": "AA00000024", "Hum": "29", "BatV": "3.01" } }`

Comment: I think it is better to use Dynamo Stream, to access the latest updated : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Comment: @Franky Thanks for your comment but as I said I am very new to this; I have enabled the stream on the table I am listening from and the Lambda function is set. But you are suggesting to get items directly from the stream? I am trying to display these values using Javascript. If you could explain your comment a bit, that would be good.

Comment: Is your goal to have one item in table #2 that is a reflection of the newest item in table #1? Or is it to replicate the entire table #1 to table #2?

Comment: @jarmod I want to have one item in table#2 that is a reflection of the newest item in table#1. Not the entire table#1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you but, did you check the dynamoDB SDK to do the insert? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property

Comment: Yes, I did go through this guide, but I did not understand how to include it in the Lambda function I have given above. I want the Lambda function to read the latest item from table#1 and put it in table#2 when an update is made in table#1 of any item. So these are different nodes with IDs and I want one row for each node ID in table#2 with the latest updated values from table#1.

Comment: It is not clear to me if what is the current state of your app or what is the problem, did you receive events into the lambda through the dynamoDB stream yet? is the lambda logging something when the dynamoDB is updated?

Comment: The Lambda function is working as expected but it is only retrieving values when an update occurs. It is not writing anything to the table#2 because I do not know what code to add after that code that I have given in my Qs post.

Comment: Could you update your question with the `event` object to see what data do you have to work with?

Comment: Please check now. I have edited the Qs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are rows with different IDs and values. I want only one row for each ID and latest values in table#2

Comment: I meant the `event` object that you receive from the DynamoDB to the Lambda. This seems mostly a matter with the data you are receiving. Should be something like ```{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventID": "7de3041dd709b024af6f29e4fa13d34c",
            "eventName": "INSERT",
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, i.e., "I want to have one item in table#2 that is a reflection of the newest item in table#1. Not the entire table#1", there are multiple ways to accomplish what you're looking for:

1. Set [BatchSize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-batchsize) to 1. Your lambda function will be called for every single change in the dynamodb table #1 and you can use [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) operation on table #2;
2. Increase [BatchSize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-batchsize) and process only the latest event in the batch. Something like:

```js
 var uniqueEvents = _.chain(event.Records)
    .reverse()
    .uniqBy(function (record) {
      return record.dynamodb.Keys.id.S;
    })
    .value();
```

Is option #2 is an option for you, it is preferable than #1 (less chatty & cheaper)